# Counting the number of tables in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with many tables.

I need to count the number of tables.

I have tried the following VBA

```
Dim T as Table
Dim i as Integer
Dim Tables as Integer

For Each T In wdDoc.Tables
    i = i + 1
    Exit For
Next
Tables = i
End sub
```

However this comes back with

> "Run-time error '424': Object required".

I also found on the internet the code

```
Tables = wdDoc.Tables.Count
```

Creating a macro with this code doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `MsgBox wdDoc.Tables.Count`?

Comment: Thank you- I combined your code with that suggested by BasDeBeer below, and the combo worked. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
   Debug.Print Active.Document.Tables.Count
```

Comment: I added "MsgBox" in front of the "Active.Document.Tables.Count" and that seemed to work.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using Word 2016, the recommended answer was still running into an error. I tried a slightly revised version combining the answer & comments above. Having a period between "Active" and "Document" caused the macro to fail. I swapped in Message Box for Debug.Print, and this worked:

```
Sub CountTables()
'
' CountTables Macro
'
'
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    
End Sub
```